# Deploy azure function with GoLang

Tags: azure, go, deployment, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

Currently I'm building a GoLang serverless Azure Function.
I use this build pipeline:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'
steps:
- task: GoTool@0
  inputs:
    version: '1.16.2'

- task: Go@0
  displayName: 'go get'
  inputs:
    arguments: '-d'
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'

- task: Go@0
  displayName: 'go build'
  inputs:
    command: build
    arguments: '-o go_ibors_backend main.go'
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
```

The build pipeline has run successfully. Also, the release pipeline is deploying successful, but when I look at my functions in the Azure Portal there are no results. When I push the function locally to Azure then all my functions are displayed.

Release task:
[image: Screenshot of the release task]

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `PublishBuildArtifacts` is depracted. Please take a look on PublishPipelineArtifacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that ArchiveFiles was directing to the wrong rootFolderOrFile and that the includeRootFolder must be put to false, because the job will look for a host.json file in the root folder.

```
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Create artifact'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true
```